# How to create a Footer with two rows of content

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm trying to create a footer that has an `lfoot` section, `rfoot` section, and then a full width section below that. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code, please.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome. // Do you really want a (long) section at the (vertically small) bottom of a page?

Comment: You can start from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275479/how-to-have-two-lines-in-fancyhdr or here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339400/multi-line-footer-alignment